i get 'Syntax error' in Gemini with laravel 11
when i use Gemini as like this :
use Gemini\Laravel\Facades\Gemini;
$result = Gemini::geminiPro()->generateContent("hello");

i get this error :
Gemini\ Exceptions\UnserializableResponse
PHP 8.3.6 laravel 11.6.0
Syntax error

syntax error in line : $result = Gemini::geminiPro()->generateContent("hello");
anybody can help me?
I went exactly to the method (https://github.com/google-gemini-php/laravel), but the result I got was top error

I would contact the owner of that third party library.  they will be able to help you better but it doesn't look like its been updated in a while.

thanks that's right, i waiting for your help

From what I have read here, and this is from a different service, the "Syntax error" happens because requests from your client were blocked.

@nikoo are you in this regions?

@nikoo ask here https://github.com/google-gemini-php/laravel/issues

@francisco Why can this block occur? my region is a switzerland

@LindaLawton-DaImTo thank you , i submit my issues in github

@nikoo because Gemini isnt available in your country https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/available-regions#available_regions

@nikoo check my  Answer and do !curl ipinfo.io and post what says

@francisco - not a good test. I have servers in NY/US that Gemini blocks because it determines the servers are in the EU because the hosting company is registered in the EU. Accurate IP geolocation is a pain today.

I recommend that you add code to handle the exception and process the error message so that you know the reason, which appears in your case to be a region availability issue.

@JohnHanley this test is in their docs to determine the location of the Colab instance.prob ipv4/ ipv6 or domain that they know accurate location, plus, Europe where? NY is not available.

@francisco - it may be suggested in the docs but that does not mean it is a reliable test. IP-based geolocation is very problematic to perform reliably. A route failure can send traffic across an ocean or to a different country.

You are being blocked, since you are from Switzerland and in Available regions you're not in one of these countries or territories, try to use Gemini Pro in Vertex AI.
These are their terms of service.
Note:

For Colab users - Region restrictions are applied based on the region that the Colab instance is in, not the region that the user is in. You can check the location of the Colab instance using !curl ipinfo.io


Yes, i try it seems to be true,
My client is not allowed to receive information from GEMINI-URL :(       What do you think is the solution? What other way is there than using Vertex AI?

@nikoo sorry I don't know any bypass to that. Just use another AI. I hope that answers all, mark as correct and/or upvote.
